# Python httplib SSL client problems

Tags: python, ssl, client, httplib

I have the following function:

```
def soap(self, xml):
    """ Transport function """
    slash = self.apiurl.find('/')
    addr = self.apiurl[:slash]
    path = self.apiurl[slash:]

    conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection(addr)
    conn.putrequest("POST", path)
    conn.putheader("Content-type", "text/xml; charset=\"UTF-8\"")
    conn.putheader("Content-length", "%d" % len(xml))
    conn.endheaders()
    conn.send(xml) 
    rez = conn.getresponse()
    content = rez.read()
    conn.close()
    return rez, content
```

When I'm trying to connect to the server with this function, I'm receiving following error:

```
    conn.endheaders()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/httplib.py", line 908, in endheaders
    self._send_output()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/httplib.py", line 780, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/httplib.py", line 739, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/httplib.py", line 1116, in connect
    self.sock = ssl.wrap_socket(sock, self.key_file, self.cert_file)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/ssl.py", line 338, in wrap_socket
    suppress_ragged_eofs=suppress_ragged_eofs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/ssl.py", line 120, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/ssl.py", line 279, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
```

Python 2.6. The strange thing, is that when I try to connect second time in a second - it's working without any problem. How to overcome this problem with SSL?  What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Why aren't you using `urllib2` to open this?  Usually, we use `urllib2`.  Also, you have two kinds of quotes.  Do this   `'text/xml; charset="UTF-8"'`.  Finally, what exception are you getting.  This is all fine-looking traceback but the actual exception has been dropped during the cut and paste.

Comment: As a side note, when using HTTPS in Python, you need to pay attention to verifying the *server* certificate, which isn't done by default (see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3704405/modifying-python-code-to-use-ssl-for-a-rest-call/3705105#3705105).)